# Instagram API - Followers - Over Time

Tags: api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to search the instagram documentation for new followers during the year, but returning in the 'insight' endpoint with the 'metric' with the 'folower' parameter it only returns 30 days back.
Is there an endpoint, in which, I return the number of followers during the year.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's documentation that I used to try to find the 'followers'.

Comment: [Documentation - Instagram - Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights)